# Regex replace multiple characters in one go

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Say I have a string: `Something [one] {to} 'three'`
now I need to replace

- `[` with `\[`
- `}` with `\}`
- `'` with `\'`

etc.

I'm using C#.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Regex.Escape Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Escapes a minimal set of characters (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,., #, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes. This instructs the regular expression engine to interpret these characters literally rather than as metacharacters.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do this purely with a regex, you could match on a lookahead for the special characters and replace that with a backslash.

```
s/(?=[\[\]'])/\\/g
```

where the character class should contain all the characters you want to escape. This also gives you more control over which characters you want to replace.

Comment: Regex.Escape solves my problem for now, but still good to know your solution. +1 and Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to be of service.